How to convert data types from pandas data frame and then write the data into a paquet file with modified data types?
I have a netCDF file. I use xarray to extract the data into a pandas dataframe call df. There is a column name valid_time, and its data type is datetime64[ns], and there is another column named latitude and its data type is float 64. So, when data extracted from netCDF to df, the same data types are inherited. Now, I need to write all data from df to a parquet file, therefore the same data types are also used in the parquet file.
However, I need to convert data type of valid_time to timestamp, and latitude to double when write the data to the the parquet file.
There are 2 reasons I must convert the data types:

The parquet files will be used in subsequent process and opened by spark.read. However, datetime64[ns] is not supported in my spark version therefore threw errors.
The schemas defined in subsequent process are timestamp and double.

The question is, how I can convert the data types within pandas data frame, and let the parquet file uses the modified schema, i.e., timestamp and double?
I'm using Databricks with cluster of 14.3 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.5.0, Scala 2.12) that executed all below codes.
Below are the key parts of the code:
# Define a function to extract given netCDF file to parquet file format
def process_my_file(path, filename, output_dir, cols):  
    dataset = xr.open_dataset('/dbfs/{}'.format(path[5:])).load()
    df = dataset.to_dataframe().reset_index()
    inter_cols = list(set(df.columns.values) & set(cols))
    df= df.query[inter_cols].reset_index().drop('index', axis=1)
    name_function = lambda x: "{}_part{}.parquet".format(filename,x)
    from_pandas(df, npartitions=1).to_parquet("/dbfs{}/".format(output_dir),name_function=name_function, write_index=False, compression="snappy",  engine="pyarrow", append=False)
    return path

#This is the main program. df_files_to_process is a dataframe that stores all netCDF files that need to be converted to parquet files. 
#Firstly, convert all netCDF file to parquet and put it to RDD for better performance.  
rdd_files_to_process = df_files_to_process.rdd
rdd_processed_files = rdd_files_to_process.map(lambda x: process_my_file(x["path"],x["filename"],output_dir, cols))
rdd_processed_files.count()

#Secondly, read all the parquet files that generate above, and do the subsequent transformation.
parq_df = spark.read.parquet("{}/*".format(output_dir))

These codes ran into error since July, and the error is: Could not read or convert schema for file.
I have compared the schema between the successful run and failed run on the df (the pandas data frame that defined in function of process_my_file),and find they are different by executing below code:
display(df.dtypes)

Successful run showed that schema of valid_time is 'timestamp', and Latitude schema is 'double' (there are logs that I can check)
Failed run showed that the schema of valid_time is 'datetime64[ns]', and Latitude schema is ' float64'.
In the failed run, I also checked the schema of the output parquet files, they are same as df, i.e., valid_time is 'datetime64[ns]', and Latitude schema is ' float64'. However, in the main program, of the second step (spark.read), it's problematic because Support for the TIMESTAMP_NANOS type is not available in in OSS Spark and DBR
I also checked the pandas document, it seems the available data type for timestamps are either datetime64[ns] or datetime64[ns, tz], and there is no option of 'timestamp'. The 'timestamp' type is only available in spark data frame.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.5.3/user_guide/timeseries.html
So, how could I resolve this issue and also satisfying below?
In the function of process_my_file, still use pandas and make data types in parquet files as 'double' and 'timestamp'. (I can not use spark data frame to replace pandas df, because the main program uses RDD for performance improvement)
Or, there is a better design to handle both performance and incompatible issue between pandas and spark dataframes' data types?

Please Provide sample Input data and expected data as well as the Input and expected dtypes per column

Thank you Samuel.  I did more search on Pandas data types, it seemed  the available data type for timestamps are either datetime64[ns] or datetime64[ns, tz], and there is no option of 'timestamp'.  Float64 is the equivalent data type of double. So, I updated the question.
